# Date conditionals not working as they should

Tags: conditionals, date

Im using this code which as of todays date should display 11 Sept but instead it displays 20 Feb?? Cant figure out what is wrong

```
{if {current_time format="%d.%m"} >= 06.11 && {current_time format="%d.%m"} <= 07.01}
6 Jan

{if:elseif {current_time format="%d.%m"} >= 06.01 && {current_time format="%d.%m"} <= 21.02}
20 Feb

{if:elseif {current_time format="%d.%m"} >= 20.02 && {current_time format="%d.%m"} <= 28.03}
27 Mar

{if:elseif {current_time format="%d.%m"} >= 27.03 && {current_time format="%d.%m"} <= 16.05}
15 May

{if:elseif {current_time format="%d.%m"} >= 15.05 && {current_time format="%d.%m"} <= 04.08}
3 Aug

{if:elseif {current_time format="%d.%m"} >= 03.08 && {current_time format="%d.%m"} <= 12.09}
11 Sept

{if:elseif {current_time format="%d.%m"} >= 11.09 && {current_time format="%d.%m"} <= 07.11}
6 Nov
{/if}
```

Comment: Aeeeyyy, can you edit your question and at least use code blocks? http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask I really can't parse your spaghetti.

Answer (score 0):

`{current_time format="%d.%m"}` is not a number (integer or decimal)
Try putting what your comparing to in double quotes.

```
{current_time format="%d.%m"} >= "06.11"
```

Then it should perform a string comparison and not a numeric one.

EDIT:
I just tested this and it works.

```
{if {current_time format="%d.%m"} >= "18.08" && {current_time format="%d.%m"} <="18.09" }Sept 11 {if:else}Ooops{/if}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer but unfortunately putting the date in double quotes as you suggest results in exactly the same output which is incorrect.

Comment: Hi, Ive tried all of the below combinations using double quotes and all result in the same wrong display. Anyone know the solution?{if "{current_time format="%F"}" == "May"}

do this:

{if "{current_time format='%F'}" == "May"}

or this:

{if "{current_time format=\"%F\"}" == "May"}